# На сайты с каким сертификатом браузеры пропускают запросы с сайтов с EV SSL сертификатом?

Tags: ajax, http, post, ssl

С сайта с EV SSL сертификатом (к примеру, сайт Facebook) должен быть отправлен AJAX POST запрос на сервер с небезопасным подключением HTTP. Так как браузеры не позволяют это осуществить, хочу взять сервер, поставить туда SSL сертификат и пользоваться им в качестве посредника. Запрос будет приходить на него, а оттуда будет отправляться на HTTP сайт.

Известно, что типов SSL сертификатов несколько.

Вопрос:

Какой тип сертификата нужно ставить на сервер, чтобы браузер пропускал AJAX POST запросы с EV SSL сайта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получите просто любой SSL-сертификат.

Основная разница межу обычными и EV-сертфикатами - второй стоит дольше, требует больше бумаг, и гораздо дольше оформляется.

Comment: Не думаю, что любой прокатит. Я сталкивался с бесплатным сертификатом, который Chrome не принимает, а Safari, к примеру, принимает. Не пробовал сделать AJAX запрос, но, думаю, Chrome бы не пропустил такого. Ну и самоподписный, как мне кажется, тоже не сработает в этом случае.

Comment: @LEQADA, подойдет любой. "Chrome не принимает, а Safari" - это скорее в настройках веб-сервера было включено использование кипера Diffie-Hellman - chrome блокирует использование такого шифрования, независимо от сертификата, т.к. оно очень уязвимо. А самоподписанные сертификаты нельзя использовать не потому, что он самоподписаные, а потому что другие пользователи не смогут удостоверить их подлинность и актуальность.

Comment: Моей целью является не обеспечение безопасности пользователя. Я хочу, чтобы браузер пустил AJAX POST запрос. То есть, он пропустит, даже если на сервере будет использоваться самоподписный сертификат?

Comment: @LEQADA, только на вашем компьютере, если вы самостоятельно добавите его в хранилище доверенных сертификатов. На других компьютерах, где сертификат не добавлен в "доверенные" - браузер естественно выдаст ошибку проверки сертификата. Т.е. самоподписанный сертификат можно использовать только для тестирования в момент разработки. В остальных случаях - нужно использовать сертификат заверенный общепринятым корневым центром сертификации.